# botbuilder DialogTestClient 's sendActivity only accepts strings and not numbers

Tags: botframework

I am using the botbuilder DialogTestClient 's sendActivity method to send prompts to my bot while testing but the method only accepts string types and in my bot i use number promts to prompt the user for numbers . Do you have any idea on how i can overturn this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit unclear if you are having this issue only for DialogTestClient or all Clients, but in nodejs you can just convert the string to number using `Number(promptInput)`. If the promptInput is already a number, it will still work fine. I assume there is a similar function in C#.

Edit: Some additional context. You can take a look at [userProfileDialog.js](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/05.multi-turn-prompt/dialogs/userProfileDialog.js) in multi-turn-prompt sample for an example. Essentially, NumberPrompt has a "succeeded" property in the recognizer that ensures you entered a number. You can use that plus whatever validations you want in the validator function. If it succeeds and is validated, a number, not a string, is passed to the next step in your dialog.

If the error is coming when you are trying to repeat back the prompt value to the user, you need to convert it to a string. I favor using the backtick for this (template string/literal), e.g.

```js
await step.context.sendActivity(`You entered ${step.result}`);
```

where `step.result` is the numberPrompt result.

Comment: Hello, 
thank you for your answer, i am using Node.js and my problem is that using NumberPrompt in my bot and i cannot send a number via client.sendActivity(any : string) and i cannot send for example "5" as a string because the numberprompt prompt would not accept the string input long before it gets to validate the input via a validation function for example . Or am i doing something wrong here ? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your code where you are reaching the error? I'm not sure where you are trying to use sendActivity where a number is required? I'm adding some additional context to the answer that may help.